# Holonomy vs structure group of tangent bundle

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles, holonomy

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, is the holonomy group of $g$ the structure group of the oriented tangent bundle on $M$?  If not, is there a relation between the two? Their definitions seem quite similar (possibly identical) to me, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: If feasible, can you please edit to add your definition of "the structure group of the oriented tangent bundle of $M$" (especially, clarification of the uniqueness article _the_) to your post? That will 1. make your question self-contained, and 2. help ensure passing volunteers give you a useful answer.